# Java Decorating The Easy Way

Tags: java, algorithm, decorator

Say you have an API that is not accessible to change:

```
List<LegacyObject> getImportantThingFromDatabase(Criteria c);
```

Imaging Legacy Object has a ton of fields and you want to extend it to make getting at certain information easier:

```
class ImprovedLegacyObject extends LegacyObject {
   String getSomeFieldThatUsuallyRequiresIteratorsAndAllSortsOfCrap() {
       //cool code that makes things easier goes here
   }
}
```

However, you can't just cast to your `ImprovedLegacyObject`, even though the fields are all the same and you haven't changed any of the underlying code, you've only added to it so that code that uses `LegacyObject` still works, but new code is easier to write.

Is it possible to have some easy way to convert `LegacyObject` to `ImprovedLegacyObject` without recreating all of the fields, or accessors?  It should be a fast opperation too, I konw you could perform something by using reflections to copy all properties, but I don't think that would be fast enough when doing so to masses of `LegacyObjects`

EDIT:  Is there anything you could do with static methods?  To decorate an existing object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to perform the copying yourself. You can either have a constructor that does this (called a copy constructor):

```
public ImprovedLegacyObject(LegacyObject legacyObject) {        
  ...
  //copy stuff over

  this.someField = legacyObject.getSomeField();
  this.anotherField = legacyObject.getAnotherField();
  ...
}
```

or you can have a static factory method that returns an `ImprovedLegacyObject`

```
public static ImprovedLegacyObject create(LegacyObject legacyObject) {
  ...
  //copy stuff over
  ...
  return improvedLegacyObject;
}
```

If you're planning on extending this behavior to other legacy objects, then you should create an interface

```
public interface CoolNewCodeInterface {

   public String getSomeFieldThatUsuallyRequiresIteratorsAndAllSortsOfCrap() {

   }

   public String getSomeFieldInAReallyCoolWay() {

   }
}
```

Then your `ImprovedLegacyObject` would look like this:

```
public ImprovedLegacyObject extends LegacyObject implements CoolNewCodeInterface {

  //implement methods from interface
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured this may be my only way to do it :o.  I was trying to avoid this because of laziness...  But it would be cool of Java had a way to do this without having to create extra objects and perform a write to all properties.  If nobody else comes up with something better I'll accept this

Answer (score 1):

How about making a copy constructor for your Improved Legacy Object that takes a Legacy Object as an argument. Then just create new objects from the old ones.

Comment: the copy constructor would manually assign each property of the old object to the new one?  Could you add just a tiny snippit of psuedo?